# Select numbers from a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

```
library("PerformanceAnalytics")
a<-seq(from=1,to=2,by=.01)
b<-table.Stats(a)
str(b)
'data.frame':   16 obs. of  1 variable:
  $ : num  101 0 1 1.25 1.5 ...
b
                      NA
Observations    101.0000
NAs               0.0000
Minimum           1.0000
Quartile 1        1.2500
Median            1.5000
Arithmetic Mean   1.5000
Geometric Mean    1.4828
Quartile 3        1.7500
Maximum           2.0000
SE Mean           0.0292
LCL Mean (0.95)   1.4422
UCL Mean (0.95)   1.5578
Variance          0.0858
Stdev             0.2930
Skewness          0.0000
Kurtosis         -1.2357
```

I need to create a data frame "s", which contains only numbers
and I don't know how to call "b" to return just numbers. Could you help me to do this?

Comment: `b` already only contains numbers. You're confusing the rownames for an actual column.  Notice how the output of `str(b)` says there's only 1 variable?

Comment: yes, this is very strangs . i have alteady try any calls but it all doesn't work

Comment: btw you can try by "table.Stats" function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is a real issue. `b` indeed contains just the numbers. The words you are seeing are the row names. A small modification of the example you give shows the creation of a data frame with two columns:

```
library("PerformanceAnalytics")
a<-seq(from=1,to=2,by=.01)
b<-table.Stats(a)
c<-seq(from=5,to=6,by=.01)
d<-table.Stats(c)
e <- cbind(b,d)
str(e)
```

Comment: it work but i really need data.frame because i run this in "while" and one of thwe easyst way is d[i+1], but with cbind this is not easy.

Comment: field2[Index]<-function(ret),Index <- Index + 1

Comment: If you want to choose a column from b in data.frame format, write b[i]. If you want a vector, write b[,i]. If you want to get rid off the column names write rownames(b) <- seq(1, nrow(b)).